# Generating unique ID for client connected to a websocket server

Tags: javascript, websocket, uniqueidentifier

Hi I want to create unique integer id for each client connected to the websocket server.

The logic is like this:

1. when a client connects to the server, it receives an id which is
   uint16.
2. The id needs to be unique so if it gets an ID that is used
   by an existing client a new one will be assigned to the client.
3. When the client leaves the websocket server the ID is recycled and is
   ready for use by incoming clients.
4. At any time there will be no more than 1000 concurrent clients, but new clients can connect at any time. I mean at any second 24/7.

What I have tried:

```
let i = Date.now();
i &= 0xFFFF;    // i will be the unique id.
```

In this way a connected client will get a 16 bit integer id. When it leaves the server there is some logic to recycle it, maybe put it into a cached array. But since there are 65535 possibilities I may not need to use that cached array.

I know that websocket connection will generate a socket id automatically once connected, but that is more than 20 bytes which is not what I want.

**Caveat:**

This method is based on the assumption that there is only one client trying to connect to the websocket server at any given time (precision is millisecond).

If two or more clients try to connect at the same time. This doesn't work. But I guess this also depends on the cpu clock rate or precisely how often a websocket server allows a new client to connect.

Comment: @JaromandaX I am generating the id on the websocket server.

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood the problem - why not just store the current ID's somewhere (db, an array, whatever, the implementation is up to you) and check that the generated ID is unique by simply checking which ones are already in use - use Math.random to generate the ID in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX The thing is if multiple clients try to connect and all of them get an ID that is already being used there will be a lot of `Math.random` calls. I am not sure about the possibilities but this could happen. And I am not sure if there would be race condition or not. Say If A calls `Math.random` and gets an existing ID now B kicks in and also asks for an ID, which gets assigned, then A receives a new ID which is being used by B. Again A needs to get a new ID right? If before it finished the `Math.random` call C comes in and the same thing happens again, A could never get an ID.

Comment: What do you think of using a Session ID? The Session ID must be a unique identifier for each server-client connection. I have had a similar scenario, and this solution has worked for me. I use Java, but I'm sure it does not matter.

Comment: @dim What is a session ID in websocket protocol? I only know that when the socket connects it is automatically assigned a base-64 encoded value, which is stored in the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header. When decoded it is 16 bytes.

Comment: I suppose this depends on the implementation of the websocket you are using. As I said, I use Java `javax.websocket.Session`(see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#getId--)). I'm not familiar with your case, but I assumed that if anything like that would help you.

Comment: @dim I am using a javascript implementation of websocket. I have checked the initial websocket protocol [RFC6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) but it doesn't mention anything about session. Maybe what you mean is the connection. If so it should be the socket id I mentioned which is 16 bytes after decoded. Does it look something like this? `dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==`

Comment: Here's an example of what an identifier looks like `f0ca4ed0-36a0-4899-a781-5cd1d216dff6`. In fact, it looks like five hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @dim this looks like a UUID to me. It has a 8-4-4-4-12 format and each hexadecimal value is 4 bit, so in total 128 bits. But I need a smaller ID such as UInt16 value to send over the wire.

Comment: @newguy - Don't sacrifice security over performance... NEVER.... use 128bit UUID and maybe even more. Security should **always** come first... This question reminds me of the pre-90's era, when nobody thought their code would need more than two digits to signify the year... This didn't work so well when the year 2000 was about to arrive and resulted in conflicts between 1901 and 2001... That was a fun time 

Answer (score 4):

Give up the idea of using a uint16 and switch to a UUID.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

These algorithms are designed for this exact type of use case.  They're well-tested and standardized.

With this method, you don't have to re-use IDs.  This is particularly handy for logging so that you can always determine what happened with a particular connection.  Additionally, it's unique across servers, so if you ever do scale up, you don't have to worry about collisions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: But I need smaller IDs not 128 bit UUID. I need to reduce the network bandwidth when sending these IDs. I don't need IDs so big. If I don't care about the bandwidth I can just use the auto-generated socket ID.

Comment: @newguy In what situation could you possibly be in that you can have all of the overhead with an HTTP request, then switching protocols, but can't have an extra couple of bytes to send a properly generated ID once?  The HTTP response status line is longer than this!

Comment: The IDs are not only sent in the response, they are also sent after the connection is established. I am building a MMO game which sends updates back and forth in 10 times per second. The IDs will be part of the message. Think about that there are 500 connected clients, sending 10 extra bytes per client per update will result in 50k more bandwidth per second. And that is only the best situation.

Comment: @newguy Why would you have to send the ID multiple times?  Once the connection is established, you can just associate the ID with that connection.  No need to send it again.

Comment: It is not the ID of the current connected client, but the IDs of other connected clients. You will not be able to know who are around you without knowing their IDs right? So in fact there will be multiple IDs sent to a client after the connection is established, making the traffic become unbearable very quickly if I use a 128 bit ID.

Comment: In addition to that, if you need to update the position of a client on the server, you have to know who is sending the action after the server receives the message, therefore the client will always need to send its ID in its message.

Comment: @newguy Ah, I get it... this has nothing to do with your web socket server after all.  You need efficient IDs for game state.  In this case, you should simply keep a counter, increment by 1 for each new client.

Comment: @newguy You're wrong about your comment regarding the client always sending its ID... you *can* and *should* associate the ID with the client, that way it doesn't need to be sent from the client at all.  It only needs to be sent in the updated game state to other clients.

Comment: What do you mean by associate the ID with the client if I am not using the socket ID?

Comment: Using a counter could also be a solution. But in this case the ID will become very big after a while, making it larger than 16 bits integer. Maybe in a week's time it grows to 1,000,000. The thing is I don't need integers so big. I will only have 1000 concurrent clients in max.

Comment: @newguy You could simply have an array or set of objects.  `const clients = new Set();  clients.add({id:25, socket: socket });`  Your ID is going to grow for sure, but you're going to have to figure that out anyway since you're probably not going to want collisions between old players and new players... and it's unlikely you'll have a time when everyone disconnects and reconnects or starts over to reset state.  You could also map the IDs to a particular compressed ID per-client, trading memory for bandwidth, allowing you to keep UUIDs.

Comment: I will not be sending the socket over the wire since the sockets are too big. Sending the socket contradicts the idea of using less bandwidth. I will only send the message with minimal data through the wire.

Comment: @newguy Obviously.  It's not even possible to usefully send the socket over the wire.  You keep that information locally on the server.  I don't know how else to explain to you that you can keep a reference to other data with your reference to your socket, so that when that socket receives data, your code and use an ID that you already have on the server.  It really makes me wonder how you're keeping track of all these sockets now...

Comment: I am keeping track of the sockets using the `Sec-Websocket-Key` header, aka socket id. But without this reference I can't. Now I want to change that. So I have to put the client id which is generated in the server in the message. Maybe this header is still in the message sent from the client, but I am not very sure.

Comment: @newguy Where are you keeping the *actual reference* to the *actual socket object* on the server?

Comment: I think the ws framework keeps the references of the connected socket objects on the server.

Comment: @newguy Show some example code of how you're sending to clients.

Comment: I am using `ws` library. The example page is here: [ws example](https://github.com/websockets/ws#usage-examples)

Comment: @newguy I'm well aware of `ws`.  Show an example of how you're sending data to clients.  Look, when you get a new connection you get a reference to the socket.  You must be doing something with that so you can reference them later.  What is it?

Comment: What are you looking for? The message I am sending is converted to binary and is very big. In the callback of `connection` listener I do something this: `function (ws, req) {  const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  console.log('connection', ip);
  ws.send('hello world.');
}`

Comment: Great! And, then what do you do with the reference to `ws`? How are you sending subsequent messages?

Comment: I will use `wss.clients` which contains a list of the connected clients to broadcast to all of them. `wss` is the websocket server instance on the server. Other than that, I can't think of other usage. If I need to reference to a particular socket I just search in the `wss.clients` to check if any one of them has a `Sec-Websocket-Key` header that matches the particular socket id. This is what I am doing now.

Comment: @newguy Got it!  Okay.  The best way to handle this is instead of using the `wss.clients` collection, make your own.  On `connection`, take `ws` from your connection handler and stick it in a Set (or Array or whatever you find convenient), along with the ID (GUID/UUID) and any other metadata you find relevant (such as a transform stream for your compressed binary transport).  When you add handlers for receiving data, bind with the ID so you know the ID based on the object.  When you send to everyone, loop through your own collection of clients (that Set of `ws`).

Comment: @newguy Another thing you can do is just stick your own metadata on the `ws` object.  `ws.newguysID = 350`  The problem with this is that you might accidentally choose a key which a future version of `ws` will use.

Comment: With regards to **take ws from your connection handler and stick it in a Set (or Array or whatever you find convenient), along with the ID (GUID/UUID) and any other metadata you find relevant**, do you mean binding the socket and ID into an object such as `{id: newID, ws:ws}` and add it into the `Set`? Or something like `map[newID] = ws`?

Comment: The reason I am using `wss.clients` is that it is maintained automatically by the library so that I have less chances to make mistakes when adding new sockets or deleting disconnected sockets.

Comment: @newguy Yes, exactly. You won't make a mistake... Just test your code.

Comment: Another problem I am facing now is that when I use the socket id/`Sec-Websocket-Key` header I can get the id from the client side. So I can match this ID with one of the IDs sent from the server. Now I have to get all the IDs from the server, but it is hard to tell which one is the current client when I receive a message on the browser side.